# connection pool in wildfly-SWARM with postgresql

Tags: java, postgresql, connection, pool, wildfly-swarm

am using postgres, wildfly-swarm, hibernate, and my transactions are bean managed.

my project-defaults.yml datasources: data-sources: part

```
 Adadawdadsa:
   driver-name: postgresql
   connection-url: dadadasdadas
   user-name: aawdwaasda
   password: waddsawdas
   jta: true
   use-java-context: true
   pool-name: awdasdadwaadads
   min-pool-size: 10
   initial-pool-size: 15
   max-pool-size: 40
   pool-prefill: false
   validate-on-match: true
   use-fast-fail: false
   connection-checker-class-name: org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.postgres.PostgreSQLValidConnectionChecker
   check-valid-connection-sql: "SELECT 1;"
   exception-sorter-class-name: org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.postgres.PostgreSQLExceptionSorter
   connection-properties: CharacterEncoding/ UTF-8 UseUnicode/true
```

After simulating a loss of connection between application and postgres (shut down DB, iptables drop packets etc, afterward doing some requests and then starting DB again or clearing iptables drop rule), DB is up but Hibernate/swarm is not able to find a connection anymore... 
Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong ?

EDIT: adding a stack trace

2017-11-23 15:16:03.180 ERROR [PgSinkTask.paymentResultToJPA.0] PgSinkTask.paymentResultToJPA.0                   : Exception on retry commit: : javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
2017-11-23 15:16:03.180 ERROR [PgSinkTask.paymentResultToJPA.0] PgSinkTask.paymentResultToJPA.0                   : Exception on retry commit: 
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1692)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1602)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1608)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.merge(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1171)
    at com.scheidtbachmann.fcs.idbt.datamart.sink.JPASinkTask.setConnectorStatus(JPASinkTask.java:297)
    at com.scheidtbachmann.fcs.idbt.datamart.sink.JPASinkTask.errorHandler(JPASinkTask.java:423)
    at com.scheidtbachmann.fcs.idbt.datamart.sink.JPASinkTask.flush(JPASinkTask.java:328)
    at com.scheidtbachmann.fcs.idbt.datamart.sink.JPASinkTask.getRecord(JPASinkTask.java:182)
    at com.scheidtbachmann.fcs.idbt.datamart.sink.JPASinkTask.run(JPASinkTask.java:144)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    at org.glassfish.enterprise.concurrent.ManagedThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThread.run(ManagedThreadFactoryImpl.java:250)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:47)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:95)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.acquireConnectionIfNeeded(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:90)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.getPhysicalConnection(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.connection(StatementPreparerImpl.java:47)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$5.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:146)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:172)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareQueryStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:148)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1929)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1898)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1876)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:919)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:336)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:306)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadEntity(Loader.java:2204)
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:60)
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:50)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3967)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:508)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:478)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:219)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:278)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doOnLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:121)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1129)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.access$2600(SessionImpl.java:164)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.load(SessionImpl.java:2696)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.get(SessionImpl.java:980)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.entityIsDetached(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:290)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:170)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:69)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireMerge(SessionImpl.java:840)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:822)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:827)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.merge(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1161)
    ... 7 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000460: Error checking for a transaction
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.getConnection(WrapperDataSource.java:146)
    at org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources.WildFlyDataSource.getConnection(WildFlyDataSource.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:386)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.acquireConnectionIfNeeded(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:87)
    ... 39 common frames omitted
Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000460: Error checking for a transaction
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.tx.TxConnectionManagerImpl.getManagedConnection(TxConnectionManagerImpl.java:424)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.allocateConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:747)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.getConnection(WrapperDataSource.java:138)
    ... 43 common frames omitted
Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000459: Transaction is not active: tx=TransactionImple < ac, BasicAction: 0:ffffc0a83842:6e69d97c:5a16d4f3:18 status: ActionStatus.ABORTED >
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.tx.TxConnectionManagerImpl.getManagedConnection(TxConnectionManagerImpl.java:408)
    ... 45 common frames omitted

EDIT: added a persistence.xml

```
<persistence-unit transaction-type="JTA" name="dadsadsadsa">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/dadsadsadsaas</jta-data-source>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false"/>
        <property name="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings" value="false"/>

        <property name="db.migration.action" value="validate-migrate"/>
        <property name="db.migration.sql.prefix" value="adadsadsadsa-"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Comment: I tested something very similar with these settings: https://github.com/wildfly-swarm/wildfly-swarm/blob/master/fractions/javaee/datasources/README.adoc#postgresql and I know it worked. Maybe try from there?

Comment: @Ladicek unfortunately it does not work :) added a stack trace

Comment: Don’t you forget about some settings in persistence.xml ?

Comment: @Yeheshuah , nothing regarding connection pool is defined in persistence.xml, added a snippet. What exactly should be declared there ? Thanks in advance, really struggling with this.

Answer (score 0):

> Hibernate's internal connection pooling algorithm is rudimentary, and is provided for development and testing purposes. Use a third-party pool for best performance and stability.

For more details, take a look at [Reference regarding connection pooling](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/devguide/en-US/html/ch01.html#d5e150), please. I found it useful.

—

### C3P0 connection pool in Hibernate (configuring)

1. Get hibernate-c3p0.jar
   To integrate c3p0 with Hibernate, you need hibernate-c3p0.jar, get it from JBoss repository.
   *pom.xml*

   JBoss repository
           http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
       <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
       <version>3.6.3.Final</version>
   </dependency>

   <!-- Hibernate c3p0 connection pool -->
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
       <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
       <version>3.6.3.Final</version>
   </dependency>
   ```
2. Configure c3p0 propertise
   To configure c3p0, puts the c3p0 configuration details in “persistence.xml“, like following:

   ```
   ...
   <properties>
     <!-- Configuring JDBC properties -->
     <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/jpa_example" />
     <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root" />
     <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="my_root_password" />
     <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />

     <!-- Hibernate properties -->
     <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
     <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
     <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect" />
     <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate" />

     <!-- Configuring Connection Pool -->
     <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size" value="5" />
     <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size" value="20" />
     <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout" value="500" />
     <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements" value="50" />
     <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period" value="2000" />
   </properties>
   ```

Maybe [c3p0 - JDBC3 Connection and Statement Pooling](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/) reference also will be helpful.